# Can you control Docker run parameters in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to run a docker container like the following:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -t container_name
```

but I'd like to specify the docker container in such a way that all I have to do is:

```
docker run container_name
```

When I EXPOSE 80, it doesn't seem to map it to the host.  Also, I don't see any command that allows me to force -t (psuedo-tty) in the Dockerfile.  CMD allows me to specify the command to run inside the container, but not the run parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Docker compose?

Comment: I'll be using this docker container with elastic beanstalk.  I just want to load it to AWS and have it work without having to manually access the server to run the container.  I'll look at any tech that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.

Both arguments require the docker demon to interact with *container and host*.

`-p 80:80` connects host and container network, `-t` attaches the host's console to the container.

This is obviously not possible from within the container / the dockerfile.

Why don't you simply write a script that does that for you?

```
docker-run <container-name>
```

Comment: Well, ultimately the goal is the load this image into AWS elastic beanstalk and just work without any manual intervention.  I need to have Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json files

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile is only about image creation. All informations about run containers need specify in run docker command.

The EXPOSE option in Dockerfile is only about -P option in run command. In that way the docker choose a random high port to map.